# Where can I find well coded projects written in swift?

Tags: swift, github, controller, ios8

I know the basics about swift.
Now I think it's much faster to learn from well written and structured example projects instead of small Tutorials.

My Topics: 
 - Navigation Controller (Storyboard) 
 - Network communication with JSON data 
 - Login/Signup mechanism

I want to build an app with a login/signup mechanism followed by a navigation controller based menu. Therefore I am looking for a professional example project.

Do you know well written open source projects (perhaps github?!) to learn how to structure my code?

How could I implement the Login/Signup screens before the navigation controller? Or should I embed them into the navigation controller?

Looking forward to your answers!

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if this question is a bit opinion-based, I would recommend you to check the tutorials from  [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/). There are many free tutorials and even eBooks to read with all the source-code.

For your two topics there are for example the following tutorials:

[Navigation Controllers in Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1)

[Working with JSON](http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know all the wenderlich Tutorials. But they don't help me now. I want to build a real app with a login screen/signup screen and then a menu based on navigation controller. There is no tutorial, which explains one master build. Just one tutorial for login and another one for navigation. I want to see one professional structure.

Comment: Well I would highly recommend you that you learn step by step. I now exactly how you feel now. You want something as closest to your app as possible. But I would recommend you that you learn each part by itself. Because otherwise you will just copy every part and you don't really learn something.

Comment: hm...learning each part okay. But how should I learn the connection between these parts? For example the issue with the login screen. Should I embed the login screen into the navigation controller or should I implement it outside?